# Calculating the probability of the average lifetime in a sample

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

**The Question**

The average lifetime of a light bulb is 3000 hours with a standard deviation of 696 hours.  A random sample of 35 bulbs is taken.

(i) Calculate the probability that the average lifetime in a sample will be between 2670.56 and 2809.76 hours?

(ii)    Calculate the probability that the average lifetime in a sample will last at least 3200 hours?

(iii)   How large of a sample needs to be taken to provide a 0.01 probability that the average lifetime in the sample will be equal to or greater than 3219.24 hours?

**My Attempt**

(i) $p(2670.56 < x < 2809.76) = p(z < -1.62) - p(z < -2.8) = 0.5$

This is correct.

(ii) $p(x > 3200) = 1 - p(x < 3200) = 1 - p(z < 1.7) = 1 - 0.9554 = 0.0446$

This too is correct.

(iii) I do not understand how would I go about this section. Tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample is of size $n$, then for the sample mean $\bar x$ you have $$\frac{\bar x - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} \sim N(0, 1)$$

$$P(\bar x \geq 3219.24) = P(z \geq \frac{3219.24 - 3000}{696}\sqrt{n}) \stackrel{!}{=} 0.01$$

So, you need to find $n$ such that

$$\frac{3219.24 - 3000}{696}\sqrt{n} = z_{0.01} = 2.33$$

I leave the calculations up to you :-).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it now. Therefore, n = 54.7, so approximately equal to 55.

Comment: Sa7 kida ya baasha. :-)